# Remove contents in side parenthesis of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove all the contents inside parenthesis of all the columns in a data frame using the following code. But I can't figure out to do it correctly. Any help is highly appreciated

```
def clean_text(data):
     if data.find('(')!=-1:
         st=data[data.find("(") + 1:data.find(")")])
         data.replace(st,'')  # cant use this
     return data.lower()


no_dup_cols = no_dup.columns.values
for col in no_dup_cols:
    no_dup[col] = no_dup[col].apply(clean_text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with loop columns and [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['(1)','2','3'],
                   'B':['(B) 77','s gg','d'],
                   'C':['s','(d) 44','f']})

print (data)
     A       B       C
0  (1)  (B) 77       s
1    2    s gg  (d) 44
2    3       d       f

for col in data:
    data[col] = data[col].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '')
print (data)
   A     B    C
0       77    s
1  2  s gg   44
2  3     d    f
```

Solution with list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
data = pd.concat([data[col].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '') for col in data], axis=1)
print (data)
   A     B    C
0       77    s
1  2  s gg   44
2  3     d    f
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd stack the entire thing into a `pd.Series`

```
sk = range(df.columns.nlevels)

df = df.stack(sk)
```

Then perform a `str.replace`

```
df = df.str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '')
```

Then unstack back

```
uk = [i * -1 - 1 for i in sk]

df = df.unstack(uk)
```

Altogether in a nice function

```
def df_replace(df, *args, **kwargs):
    sk = range(df.columns.nlevels)
    uk = [i * -1 - 1 for i in sk]

    return df.stack(sk).astype(str).str.replace(*args, **kwargs).unstack(uk)
```

Use it like you would `str.replace`

```
df_replace(df, r'\(.*\)', '')
```

---

#### Timing

Conclusion is that my solution looks clever but is a bit slow... Or put another way, jezrael's solutions are faster.

**code**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':['(1)','2','3'],
                   'B':['(B) 77','s gg','d'],
                   'C':['s','(d) 44','f']})

def jez1(data):
    data = data.copy()
    for col in data:
        data[col] = data[col].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '')
    return data

def jez2(data):
    return pd.concat([data[col].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '') for col in data], axis=1)

def pir(data):
    return df_replace(data, r'\(.*\)', '')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add timings for comparing my and your solution?

Comment: I try add timings too, but some erorr in your function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with panda but if data is a string type, than you should do

```
data = data.replace(st, '')
```

instead of

```
data.replace(st,'')
```

cf. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Is it possible to have a data sample and a more precise example of what you expect to have as a result please? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data[col] = data[col].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '')
```