# Using Pandas to Manipulate Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 30+ million row data set that I need to apply a whole host of data transformation rules to.  For this task, I am trying to explore Pandas as a possible solution because my current solution isn't very fast.

Currently, I am performing a row by row manipulation of the data set, and then exporting it to a new table (CSV file) on disk.

There are 5 functions users can perform on the data within a given column:

1. remove white space
2. Capitalize all text
3. format date
4. replace letter/number
5. replace word

My first thought was to use the dataframe's apply or applmap, but this can only be used on a single column.

Is there a way to use apply or applymap to many columns instead of just one?
Is there a better workflow I should consider since I could be doing manipulations to 1:n columns in my dataset, where the maximum number of columns is currently around 30.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) if need apply some function working only with `Series`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[' ff ','2','3'],
                   'B':[' 77','s gg','d'],
                   'C':['s',' 44','f']})

print (data)
      A     B    C
0   ff     77    s
1     2  s gg   44
2     3     d    f

print (pd.concat([data[col].str.strip().str.capitalize() for col in data], axis=1))
    A     B   C
0  Ff    77   S
1   2  S gg  44
2   3     D   F
```

Comment: wouldn't this affect performance given the size of my dataset?  If I had to loop the list 30+ million times say 5 or 6 times?

Comment: Yes, it is the fastest solution, see [timings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38562413/2901002) in similar answer.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try and let you know how I make out! Thank you

Comment: Yes, but I think 30M rows is huge, so it can be still  slow (although it is fastest solution).

Comment: very true, 30M is large, that is why I'm trying to find the best solution. I've hit a wall.